# 'Subscribers' tab does not display customer version (LMA)

Tags: salesforce

When I click onto the 'Subscribers' tab I see the following (uneditable) fields.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJmFo.png

I must then click on each Org individually, this takes me to the clients instance and displays the info I need:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zhia0.png

Essentially, I need to be able to query the 'Current Version' field.

Is this possible? (Through the API/Workbench etc)

Thanks.

Comment: `Subscriber` is not a standard object, so sounds like you're working with a custom object. Please provide more details about how the page is created and what you're currently doing for querying the fields.